# Json iteration fails when there is one sub object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm converting an xml string to json using php and then posting it to a 
javascript file where I try to iterate it. When the object contains more than one object, json contains an array of objects like the first sample and I can iterate using the `.length` function but when the object contains only 1 object an array is not being created and the `.length` function fails. How can I make the iteration work in both cases without knowing the object's name?

Sample 1:

```
{"class":[
   {
      "name":"history",
      "grade":"10"
   },
   {
      "name":"chemistry",
      "grade":"8"
   }
  ]
}
```

Sample 2:

```
{"class":
   {
      "name":"history",
      "grade":"10"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check `length`, and if it's `undefined` it means it's just an object, then you make it an array with just one element:

```
if collection.length == undefined:
  collection = [collection]

# the rest of the code doesn't need to be changed
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` for that and you don't need `length`

```
var test = {"class":[
   {
      "name":"history",
      "grade":"10"
   },
   {
      "name":"chemistry",
      "grade":"8"
   }
  ]
}

for (var i in test){
    console.log(test[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the object is an array first:  `Array.isArray(obj)` . If it isn't then you know you don't need to iterate it.

```
var obj = {"class":[
   {
      "name":"history",
      "grade":"10"
   },
   {
      "name":"chemistry",
      "grade":"8"
   }
  ]
}

if (!Array.isArray(obj)) return obj;
// else iterate it.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the data type of the variable before knowing how to use `.length` properly.

```js
var dataTypeLength;
var data = {
 "class":
   {
     "name":"history",
     "grade":"10"
   }
}

if (Array.isArray(data.class)) {
  dataTypeLength = data.class.length;
} else {
  dataTypeLength = Object.keys(data.class).length;
}

console.log(dataTypeLength);
```